# MVC Core 1.1: System.Web namepspace

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I had a project in ASP.net and now I am changing it to MVC Core 1.1. Previously I used assembly reference **System.Web** to access features like **XmlDocument, ConfigurationManager** etc. But now MVC core **doesnot recognise System.Web**. Can anyone please suggest which nuget package should I add to make this reference available.

Currently Installed packages :-

- Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor

I have already updated them to the lastest version. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: You should really google this - most of the classes were moved to a different namespace/nuget packages(XmlDocument -> System.Xml.XmlDocument) and some classes like the ConfigurationManager were deprecated in favor of different mechanisms.

Comment: Thank you. Should I search for every class that's giving error?

Comment: The configuration mechanism has changed, appsetting.json has replaced web.config. So, changing the nuget package may not help you, you may need to change the code to core style of reading the application settings

Comment: @Akshay Sharma yes, that is the easiest way to see what exists inside asp.net core and what is removed/replaced.

Comment: XmlDocument is replaced as XDocument in asp.net core. Use System.Xml.Linq namespace.

Answer (score 0):

You can Create a New Project in Asp.net Core Framework.
It installs all Pakeges at runtime when application Build.
I advise you to Create New web Appliaction